# remove Special characteres using phpmailer

Tags: php

How to avoid special characters using this script?

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
include("class.smtp.php");
$mail    = new PHPMailer();
$name    = $_REQUEST['name'];
$email   = $_REQUEST['email'];
$message = $_REQUEST['comments'];
//$body             = 
file_get_contents('contents.html');
//$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "smtp.office365.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Host       = "smtp.office365.com";
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->Username   = "***@ac.in";
$mail->Password   = "*******";
$mail->SetFrom('***@ac.in', 'First Last');
$mail->Subject = "Feedback";
$mail->AltBody = $comments;
if(!$mail->Send()) 
{ 
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo; 
} 
else 
{ 
   echo "Message sent! Thank you for your feedback."; 
}
```

Sometimes I'm received below output, can anyone help regarding this?

OUTPUT:

> nationâ€™s
>
> nation's its comes nationâ€™s

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please format your code, and link image directly to question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mb_convert_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php).

**Code :**

```
$mail->AltBody    = mb_convert_encoding($comments, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
```

This will remove all non UTF-8 characters.

for details refer [mb_convert_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

**Updated Code :**

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');
require_once ('class.phpmailer.php');

include ("class.smtp.php");

 // optional, gets

calledfromwithinclass . phpmailer . php

if notalreadyloaded $mail = new PHPMailer();
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$message = $_REQUEST['comments'];

// $body             =

file_get_contents('contents.html');

// $body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "smtp.office365.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // enables SMTP
debuginformation(
for testing) // 1 = errors and messages
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // enable SMTP
authentication $mail->Host = "smtp.office365.com"; // sets the
SMTPserver $mail->Port = 587; // set the SMTP port for the
GMAILserver $mail->Username = "***@ac.in"; // SMTP account
username $mail->Password = "*******"; // SMTP
accountltpassword $mail->SetFrom('***@ac.in', 'First Last');
$mail->Subject = "Feedback";
$mail->AltBody =  mb_convert_encoding($comments, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
?>
```

Comment: $mail->AltBody    = mb_convert_encoding($comments, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');                       this too try but it getting error for blank page no mail received

Comment: I have not seen any call to $mail->send() in your code ?

Comment: $body = "Dear Sir  !

Name of the Candidate : $name
Email id : $email
Comments : $message";
$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "*****";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "*****");

//$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
//$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent! Thank you for your feedback.";
}                                sryy... forgot to upload

Comment: var_dump($mail->AltBody) and tell me output.

Comment: var_dump($mail->AltBody);    using this the problem happens no mail received and blak page

Comment: what output you get on var_dump() ?

Comment: am get blank action page only no email received

Comment: there must be some error, set error reporting on by using this code.  ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);